# How to pause a specific thread after an interval in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have three thread group in test plan just like that

Thread group 1: 1 thread forever
Thread group 2: 10 thread forever
Thread group 3: 1 thread forever

**Question**: How to pause Thread group 2 for 3 seconds after every 10 minutes?

**Note**: During the pause period of Thread group 2, Thread group 1 and Thread group 3 should be in working condition.

Comment: How Thread group 2 is defined ? Infinite loop ? 1 Thread? can you add more details

Comment: @user7294900 question edited, forever is infinite in JMeter.

Comment: @user7294900 Do I need to write Groovy code for the above problem? If yes can you give me some hint about this?